# How to make two Joins generate one select?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I currently have 3 tables:

```
News
ID | Title

Tag
ID | Name

TaggedContent
ContentID | TagID
```

And I have two context objects: `NewsEntities` and `TagsEntities`

I want to select all tags used by News, in my application I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> something = null;

    IEnumerable<News.Data.News> news = null;
    IEnumerable<Tags.Data.Tag> tags = null;
    IEnumerable<TaggedContent> tagged = null;

    using (var db = new NewsEntities())
    {
        news = db.News.ToList(); // 1 select
    }

    using (var db = new TagsEntities())
    {
        something = news.Join(db.TaggedContents.ToList(),
            n => n.ID,
            tc => tc.ContentID,
            (n, tc) => new { tc.TagID }); // 1 select

        something = something.Join(db.Tags.ToList(),
            tid => tid.TagID,
            t => t.ID,
            (tid, t) => t); // 1 select
    }

    var result = something;
}
```

I am currently generating **3 selects. How can I reduce it to 2?** Or if possible I would like to reduce to 1 without merging the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're joining entities from different contexts, you can't get away with fewer than 2 selects.

Your join is a simple identity check, so you could do this:

```
var ids = db.News.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

You now have a local copy of all of the IDs in the news table -- the first select. Then change your first 'something' to:

```
something = db.TaggedContents
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.ContentID))
    .Select(x => new { x.TagID });
```

This second statement won't in itself generate a select because of deferred execution. You can now remove the `ToList()` in the third statement:

```
something = something.Join(db.Tags,
    tid => tid.TagID,
    t => t.ID,
    (tid, t) => t);
```

And when you finally enumerate over `something`, you'll have your second select.

Answer (score 0):

Using DataLoadOptions class passed in the creation of your DataContext.

```
       DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
       db.LoadOptions = options;
       options.LoadWith((News n) => n.Tags);
```

So do for the remaining of the data to join.

Comment: DataLoadOptions are part of Linq-To-Sql not entity framework.